# Generate vertices on line with respect to point on line

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I have a road layer in line and point layer snap over line i.e. road layer.
I had use QGIS 3.4 "snap geometry to layer" but no vertices are generated on the line layer.
Now I want to generate vertices on line with respect to point feature.
How to do it in QGIS?

Comment: _"no vertices are generated on the line layer"_ : what do u mean ? snapping options only apply when you're adding your vertices **manually** ... so ... how are your vertices generated ?

Comment: There is option in QGIS 3.4, 'snap geometry to line' insert vertices  where required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a tool to add vertices to a line. Instead, you can follow this process:

1. **Split the line at the points.** The easiest way is to use the SAGA tool `Split lines at points`. This tool has been buggy in the past, and I'm not sure if it will work for you. If it doesn't work, follow this longer method:

   I. Use `geometry by expression` to convert the points to short lines (use an expression like `make_line($geometry, make_point($x + 1, $y + 1))`.

   II. Make sure the lines created in step I don't cross over the road lines more than once.

   III. Use the QGIS algorithm `Split with lines` to split the road lines with the lines created in step I.
2. **Re-join the split lines** with the `Dissolve` tool. Hopefully the road lines still have those vertices. If not, `extract vertices` of the split lines. Connect the verteces into lines with `points to path`.